# Flex selectedItem problems

Tags: apache-flex, list, drop-down-menu

I have encountered somthing a little strange in flex, possibly somthing im doing wrong 
but im not sure.

In two cases which i have noticed, when there is only 1 item in a s:List or s:DropDownList 
for some reason when using list.selectedItem it appears as null. Using requireSelection="true"
i know this isnt the case.

Has anyone else seen anything similar? or am i doing it completly wrong?
Thanks 
Jon

Edit: In the code bellow it happens when clicking the edit document, which calls the open edit method

------------ Added Code ---------------------------

I have removed small portions to make it more readable

```
<s:TitleWindow width="486" height="300" title="Document Store"
               xmlns:tmsbean="services.tmsbean.*"
               close="close()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:CallResponder id="getAllAttachedDocumentsResult"/>
        <tmsbean:TMSBean id="tMSBean" showBusyCursor="true"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="removeDocumentLinkResult" result="getDocumentList()"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[


        private static var documentStoreView:DocumentStoreView = null;
        [Bindable]
        private var attachedToMenomic:String;

        public static function getInstance():DocumentStoreView
        {
            if(documentStoreView == null){
                documentStoreView = new DocumentStoreView();
                DocumentForm.getInstance().addEventListener(DocumentFormEvent.DOCUMENT_ATTACHED,documentStoreView.getDocumentList);
            }
            return documentStoreView;
        }

        public function open(menomic:String,parent:DisplayObject):void
        {
            attachedToMenomic = menomic;
            getDocumentList();
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(documentStoreView,parent,true);
            PopUpManager.centerPopUp(documentStoreView);
            y = y - 80;
        }

        public function close():void
        {
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(documentStoreView);
        }

        private function getDocumentList(evt:DocumentFormEvent = null):void
        {
            getAllAttachedDocumentsResult.token = tMSBean.getAllAttachedDocuments(attachedToMenomic);
        }


        private function openEdit():void{
            var editDsi:DocumentStoreItem = documentList.selectedItem as DocumentStoreItem;
            Alert.show(editDsi.documentName);
            DocumentForm.getInstance().openInEditMode(editDsi,this);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:VGroup left="10" top="10" right="10" bottom="10">
    <s:List width="100%"  height="100%" id="documentList" itemRenderer="com.documentStore.DocumentItemListRenderer" 
            dataProvider="{Utilitys.toArrayCollection(getAllAttachedDocumentsResult.token.result)}" />
    <s:HGroup horizontalAlign="right" width="100%">
        <s:Button label="Attach Document" click="{DocumentForm.getInstance().open(attachedToMenomic,this)}"/>
        <s:Button label="Edit Document" click="openEdit()"/>
    </s:HGroup>
</s:VGroup> 
</s:TitleWindow>
```

Comment: List.selectedItem seems to be working for me when there is a singular item and requireSelection="true" is set. Perhaps post some code? After what event are you inspecting the list?

Comment: I have attache my code above (removed a few bits to cut it down) in the openEdit method. A null pointer is thrown at the alert if a signle item is in the list (cannot acsess properties of null pointer), when there are two or more, it displays the data without question.

Answer (score 2):

By default Spark's DropDownList displays a [prompt](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DropDownList.html#prompt) if `selectedIndex` is -1, which will be the case if `requireSelection` is false and you have not otherwise set the list to a specific item.  This would correspond with `selectedItem` being null.

The Spark [ComboBox](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ComboBox.html) does something similar but it has a TextInput as you can type into it.